SSH, how do i know username and password? why arent my tunnels working?
So ssh is something new i discovered, i want to bypass a network guard i made for experience, i cant seem to understand how ssh -N -L localhost:8000:localhost:80 root@servername now. i understand the stuff till localhost:80 after that, what does root@myip or whatever do? i tried to do to root@(dig +short google.com)(in brackets because i dont want risk of revealing my ip although it is not related to it), i cant find any videos on this. please help, i just need an explaination of how it works!

root@myip means you want to login as root on the system at myip - root@(dig +short google.com) won't do anything special, did you mean root@$(dig +short google.com) - and if so, I highly doubt you have root access to any google.com server - have you read man ssh? it's amazing you know the relatively complex parameters to create a tunnel, but have no clue about how to establish a connection in the first place

You're trying to understand it backwards – forget about tunnels for a moment; you have to start with the "root@whatever" part.
At its core, SSH is a remote logon tool. When you run ssh someuser@somehost in your local terminal, you log in to that system's terminal, using that system's accounts. (It is not a tunneling oriented service, it just happens to have that as an extra feature.)
In this context, root@... means "log in using the 'root' account" which is the administrator account on Linux and similar systems.
C:\Users\grawity> ssh star
Last login: Fri Jul 26 10:02:41 2024 from 10.147.1.4
 12:03:45 up 387 days, 14:42, 2 users, load average: 0.01, 0.00, 0.00
(✨grawity@star) ~ $

$ ssh root@ember
Last login: Mon Feb 12 18:26:59 2024 from 10.147.1.5
[root@ember ~]# whoami
root
[root@ember ~]#

So to start with, you need to already have access to some Linux server somewhere that you're allowed to log in to. If it's your own server somewhere, then you know the username and password because you've set them up yourself (or maybe the hosting company gave you the password). If it's a friend's, then they give you a username. And if it's a random system like google.com – generally you're not allowed to SSH to it, period.
(Because it is not always obvious: If you have a server that you're using PuTTY to connect to, it uses exactly the same SSH protocol, so your "PuTTY username" and "SSH username" would be one and the same.)
The tunnel feature (-L option) runs through the same SSH connection as a side-channel. In your example, the SSH client listens on localhost:8000 on your system and requests the SSH server to connect to its localhost:80. Finally the -N option turns off the main "interactive shell" channel and leaves just the tunnel.
